# How to open certain window in Windows using python and win32gui?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to code a python program, that will open a certain window if I'm inactive (not pressing any keys in a certain amount of time). But after opening this window (hwnd) and switching focus to another window, an exception appears.

```py
import time
import keyboard as k
import win32gui


class TimeoutExpired(Exception):
    pass


def disable_mode(timeout, timer=time.time):
    endtime = timer() + timeout
    while timer() < endtime:
        if k.is_pressed('`') or k.is_pressed('w') or k.is_pressed('a') or k.is_pressed('s') or k.is_pressed('d') or k.is_pressed('Enter') or k.is_pressed('Backspace') or k.is_pressed('f') or k.is_pressed('g') or k.is_pressed('h') or k.is_pressed('j') or k.is_pressed('k') or k.is_pressed('l') or k.is_pressed('0') or k.is_pressed('1') or k.is_pressed('2') or k.is_pressed('3') or k.is_pressed('4') or k.is_pressed('5') or k.is_pressed('6') or k.is_pressed('7') or k.is_pressed('8') or k.is_pressed('9'):
            endtime = timer() + timeout
        time.sleep(0.04)
    raise TimeoutExpired


while True:
    try:
        disable_mode(5)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        try:
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Записки")
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: If you are talking about an exception, then it is better to quote its text.